# How do I export an InDesign document to separate files with a different layer turned on in each?

Tags: adobe-indesign, layers, export, indesign-scripting

I have a one-page InDesign document with 50+ layers. Each layer contains a single logo file, and I need to export the document to a PDF with one layer turned on per page. Ideally, I'd like to export to individual PDF documents, but it would be okay to export to a multi-page PDF as well, and break the PDF into single pages later if needed.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you can't have 50x pages with a logo per page, rather than 50x layers?

Comment: I've considered this, however we'll be using this InDesign document as a template for creating other pages in the future, and there is a good chance that not all logos will be needed for all documents. Therefore, we wouldn't want to export 50+ pages if it wasn't necessary. I may end up doing this though, thanks!

Comment: Also, there are several situations where we would want more than one logo layer on the page, so we've set up layers for certain logos where they're placed on the left/center/right. This allows us to turn on multiple layers without them overlapping, and have a big variety of layouts to choose from.

Comment: @Icicozi I see. In that case you might want to look at [this answer](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20511/how-to-export-layers-as-files-in-indesign#answer-21433) and also [Output Factory by Zevrix](http://zevrix.com/outputfactory.php) - it's a plugin for InDesign that provides automation and batch handling for output. It can also support for outputting layers as individual files.

Comment: @Dre thanks! I found that answer earlier but I tried it and it basically put all of my layers onto one page and made a mess. I will definitely try Output Factory, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I have recently started using the [InDesign Page Exporter Utility Script](http://www.rrdonnelley.com/prepress/prepare/indesign/indesign-exporter-utility-script.aspx) and i can confirm this does what you need. It gives you the option to export each layer as a separate PDF via a simple interface.

Comment: This sounds like a great tool, however I don't need to export the individual layers, I need to export the page itself with each layer on the page. (ex: export Page 1 with Layer 1, Page 1 with Layer 2, Page 1 with Layer 3, etc.)

Comment: Thats what it does mate. Try it :) It basicly lets you play with the layers. Meaning you define Page 1 as your always on base layer, then all the other layers and individually set to on/off and each combo is saved as a pdf.

Comment: Update: I have tried this and it really is awesome! Would recommend to anyone else who's looking for a free solution to a similar problem.

Comment: Can Exporter Utility Script. Take a multi page Indesign document and make those pages one page but different layers?